# Zabbix Disk Monitoring showing value: no data

Tags: amazon-ec2, disk-space-utilization, zabbix

I'm running Zabbix 2.2.3 and for all my Amazon linux machines it shows the correct total amount of disk space but the free space is listed as "Value: No Data".

I have another Ubuntu machine and disk space shows up just fine for that machine.

When I run the following on any of my machines it shows the correct number.
zabbix_agent -t vfs.fs.size[/]

Comment: I should mention this is only happening on the "Graphs" the other places that list free disk space are working correctly.

- Brett

Comment: What have you tired? And what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

most likely that item is updated not that often and values are not included in one hour graph (default period).
try to increase the displayed period.